# What's the generalisation of right-continuous to non-handed spaces?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, terminology

A function $f$ is right continuous at a point $c$ if it is defined on an interval $[c, d]$ lying to the right of $c$ and if $\lim_{x→c^+}f(x) =f(c)$.

Moving deliberately into less precise language, I interpret this to mean the function is continuous *when approached from the right* and it seems reasonable that in the more general setting of topological spaces outside of $\Bbb R$, *when approached from the right* can be replaced with *when approached through some subspace $X$*.  Then we might reasonably say the function is $X$-continuous.

Question: Assuming all this is reasonable, what are the proper terminology and definitions for this type of continuity?

As a background only, I have a specific interest in the fact that the function $f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$, which is continuous in the 2-adic metric space, can only approach the number $0$ *through the subspace $\{2^i:i\in\Bbb Z\}$*, if and only if the Collatz conjecture is true.  Of course, I appreciate that since it is continuous, $f$ is $\{2^i:i\in\Bbb Z\}$-continuous is a vacuous statement but I want to find where to learn about and how to talk about $X$-continuity nevertheless.

Comment: I don't know of any established notions, but you can formalize your idea by defining that a function $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces with $S\subseteq X$ is continuous at $s\in S$ from $S$ if the restricted function $f\vert_S:S\to Y$ is continuous at $s$ with respect to the subspace topology.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos I don't know how often it comes up, but "The restriction to $S$ is continuous at $s$" is certainly clear, and I think your comment could basically be reposted as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Vercassivelaunos .  In the absence of any other suggestions I'd post that as an answer if I were you. It may seem only trivial but it will be useful for others when they make a relevant search and having an accepted answer will remove this question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an established terminology, but you could just define:

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $S\subseteq X$ and $f:X\to Y$. We call $f$ "continuous at $s\in S$ when approached through $S$" if the restricted function $f\vert_S:S\to Y$ is continuous at $s$ with respect to the subspace topology on $S$.

As Mark S. suggested, "the restriction to $S$ is continuous" is probably clear enough that introducing such nomenclature isn't really needed, though.